# Getting Unique values in a group By in R with flagged columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table like this in R. Each record is a food cafe and a food cafe that can have many restaurants inside.
I want to get the unique regulations for each food cafe at the restaurant level. The table looks like this:

```
mc_d burger_king pizza_hut  wendys  regulation_id
  0       1        1           1        101
  1       0        0           1        101
  1       1        0           1         29
  0       0        0           1         17
```

and this is the intended output:

```
restaurant  | unique_regulations
--------------------------------
mc_d        |    2
burger_king |    2
pizza_hut   |    1
wendys      |    3
```

I want to do this using dplyr. I tried using a case when statement like below but that doesn't actually work. For example if there is a row with both mc_d and burger_king flagged as 1, it will be labeled as mc_d, when it's actually also burger_king.

```
food_cafe %>%
          mutate(restaurant = case_when(mc_d == 1 ~ "mc_d",
                                  burger_king == 1 ~ "burger_king",           
                                  pizza_hut == 1 ~ "pizza_hut",
                                  wendys == 1 ~ "wendys")) %>%
          group_by(restaurant) %>%
          summarise(unique_regulations = n_distinct(regulation_id))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the data in long format and for each `name` count unique `regulation_id` where `value = 1`.

```
library(dplyr)

food_cafe %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -regulation_id) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(unique_regulations = n_distinct(regulation_id[value == 1]))

#  name        unique_regulations
#  <chr>                    <int>
#1 burger_king                  2
#2 mc_d                         2
#3 pizza_hut                    1
#4 wendys                       3
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** We can reshape into 'long' format, filter by the binary column and then do a `group_by` `n_distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
food_cafe %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = -regulation_id, names_to = 'restaurant') %>% 
     filter(as.logical(value)) %>%
     # or use
     # filter(value == 1) %>%
    group_by(restaurant) %>% 
    summarise(unique_regulations = n_distinct(regulation_id))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  restaurant unique_regulations
#  <chr>       <int>
#1 burger_king     2
#2 mc_d            2
#3 pizza_hut       1
#4 wendys          3
```

---

**2)** Or without reshaping, we can do a group_by `any`, then `transpose` the dataset and do a `rowSums`

```
food_cafe %>% 
   group_by(regulation_id) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), any))  %>%
   data.table::transpose(., make.names = 'regulation_id',
          keep.names = 'restaurant') %>%
   transmute(restaurant, unique_regulations = rowSums(.[-1]))
#    restaurant unique_regulations
#1        mc_d                  2
#2 burger_king                  2
#3   pizza_hut                  1
#4      wendys                  3
```

---

**3)** Or a variation of the above

```
food_cafe %>%
    group_by(regulation_id) %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), any)) %>%
    select(-1) %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), sum)) %>% 
    pivot_longer(everything())
```

---

**4)** Or with `colSums` and `enframe`

```
library(tibble)
food_cafe %>% 
    group_by(regulation_id) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), any)) %>% 
    select(-1) %>%
    colSums %>%
    enframe
```

---

**5)** Or using `melt` (to reshape to long format) from `data.table` after converting the data.frame to data.table (`setDT`), then specify the logical index in `i`, do a group by and count the number of distinct elements with `uniqueN`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(food_cafe), id.var = 'regulation_id')[as.logical(value), 
    .(unique_regulation = uniqueN(regulation_id)),.(restaurant = variable)]
#    restaurant unique_regulation
#1:        mc_d                 2
#2: burger_king                 2
#3:   pizza_hut                 1
#4:      wendys                 3
```

---

**6)** Or using `base R`, convert the 'data.frame' to `table` class while setting the row names, reshape into 'long' format by converting to data.frame (`as.data.frame`), `subset` the rows where 'Freq' is 1, get a `table` of `unique` rows of subset of columns and get the `rowSums` (if needed `stack` it to two column data.frame)

```
stack(rowSums(table(unique(subset(as.data.frame.table(`row.names<-`(
       as.matrix(food_cafe[-5]), food_cafe[[5]])), Freq == 1)[2:1]))))[2:1]
#          ind values
#1        mc_d      2
#2 burger_king      2
#3   pizza_hut      1
#4      wendys      3
```

---

**7)** Or a one-liner with `rowSums/aggregate` in `base R`

```
stack(colSums(aggregate(.~ regulation_id, food_cafe, any)[-1]))[2:1]
#          ind values
#1        mc_d      2
#2 burger_king      2
#3   pizza_hut      1
#4      wendys      3
```

---

**8)** Or another base R option with `by/colSums`

```
stack(colSums(do.call(rbind, by(food_cafe[-5], 
          food_cafe$regulation_id, FUN = colSums)) > 0))[2:1]
#          ind values
#1        mc_d      2
#2 burger_king      2
#3   pizza_hut      1
#4      wendys      3
```

#### data

```
food_cafe <- structure(list(mc_d = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), burger_king = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), pizza_hut = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), wendys = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), regulation_id = c(101L, 101L, 29L, 17L)), class = "data.frame", 
     row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use base R:

```
df <- data.frame(mc_d = c(0,1,1,0),
             burger_king= c(1,0,1,0),
             pizza_hut=c(1,0,0,0),
             wendys=c(1,1,1,1),
             regulation_id=c(101,101,29,17))

col_reg <- 5
unique_regulations <- unlist(lapply(1:4, function(x)length(unique(df[which(df[,x] == 1),col_reg]))))
restaurant <- colnames(df)[-5]
data.frame(restaurant,unique_regulations)
```